# Send Email if get content of file more than 2 line

Tags: powershell

This script will be sending email to myself if more than 2 lines (3rd lines onwards). I tried on below script but not managed to get any email notification. 
SMTP server is working fine and no issue. May I know what problem with my code?

Tools:

1. Using powershell v2.0
2. Using .Net 4
3. Window Server 2008

> ```
> $Output = ".\Name.txt"
>
> If (Get-Content -Path $Output | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 2})
> {
>     $MailArgs = @{
>             'To'          = "myemail@company.com"
>             'From'        = "from@company.com"
>             'Subject'     = "Pending. "
>             'Attachments' =  $Output
>             'Body'        = "Please close it"
>
>             'SmtpServer' = "exchangeserver.com"
>     }
>
>     Send-MailMessage @MailArgs
> }
> ```

Example of Output File will send email

```
| Name | PassportNo |    DOB     |                                      |
+------+------------+------------+--------------------------------------+
| A    | IDN7897    | 29-08-1980 | << once got this row will send email |
| B    | ICN5877    | 14-08-1955 |                                      |
| C    | OIY7941    | 01-08-1902 |                                      |
+------+------------+------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: `If (Get-Content -Path $Output | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 2}) {..}` --> `If ((Get-Content -Path $Output).Count -gt 2) {..}`

Comment: PowerShell 2.0 is over a decade old. Yes, it still runs, but there have been significant improvements and security fixes. https://4sysops.com/wiki/differences-between-powershell-versions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, your If test is wrong.

Using `If (Get-Content -Path $Output | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 2})` you are piping each single line from the file and test if the .Count property on that single line is greater than 2 (which of course is never the case)

Change the If into

```
If ((Get-Content -Path $Output).Count -gt 2)
```

so the .Count property will give you the total number of lines in the file.