# Windows Batch With Powershell Send-MailMessage - Half the Line Breaks Not Showing

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, line-breaks

I have a windows batch file that calls another windows batch file, then calls a powershell send-mailmessage command depending on the results, however the Send-MailMessage appears to be stripping half of the line breaks when it is displayed in the email. We are using Outlook 2013 I believe & I'm currently testing on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard (powershell v2).

I've opened the results file in Notepad++ & I can see the carriage return & line feed symbols at the end of every line (CR & LF) & it displays fine in Notepad++.

I even tried commented out the call to the 2nd batch file & just manually created another results file (eg: line 1 line 2 etc on multiple lines) but it displays fine when it is emailed yet the results file generated from calling the 2nd batch file does not.

Any ideas please?

Here is an example of what it looks like

```
@REM Prepares a log file that is to be used as the body of an email.
call "C:\SCRIPTS\find_exceptions.bat" 1>C:\SCRIPTS\results.log 2>&1

IF %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
    echo No exceptions found, no email required.
    exit /b 0
)

powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer mail.domain.net -To dummy@domain.com -From dummy2@domain.com -Subject 'My Subject' -Body ("Get-Content -Path C:\SCRIPTS\results.log | Out-String" )
```

Comment: Try `Get-Content -Path c:\SCRIPTS\results.log -Raw` instead

Comment: Thanks I tried adding "` -Raw`" directly after the filename & before "`| Out-String`" but it errored:
`Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Raw'.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand`

Comment: No, lose the out-string and don’t forget the - in -Raw

Comment: Thanks but it won't work as Windows Server 2008 R2 has PowerShell V2 not V3, the -raw is a V3 command apparently

Comment: Yes that is correct. Definitely recommend upgrading to wmf 5.1.. did you try just get content by itself?

Comment: you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58660017/send-email-if-get-content-of-file-more-than-2-line)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `-Body (Get-Content -Path 'C:\SCRIPTS\results.log' | Out-String)` ?

Comment: You need to escape the double quotes in the code and Theo his comment about out-string is valid too. Try this: `powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "& {Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer mail.domain.net -To dummy@domain.com -From dummy2@domain.com -Subject 'My Subject' -Body (Get-Content -Path """C:\SCRIPTS\results.log"""" | out-string)}"`

Comment: Doug - thanks but upgrading is not an option right now unfortunately & yes removing `|Out-String` errors with cant convert object to string reqd by body parameter.

Comment: Theo - thanks but removing the double quotes & adding single quotes around filename errors with `Out-String` is not recognised as an internal or external command.

Comment: Gerhard - thanks but this isn't a powershell script, it's a powershell command in a windows batch script, so I don't have the same full functionality avail, although I am a newby to powershell & have a lot to learn. I'm not sure how that link can help me.

Comment: Peter - thanks but that command errors with `Out-String is not recognized as an internal or external command`. If I just escape a double quote with an extra double quote, it causes the same error. I thought I didn't need single quotes around a filename/path unless there is a space in it, hence why I didn't use them, however I needed the double quotes around the entire `get-content` command including the `| out-string` in order for it to not error.

Comment: Did you try and copy my full example of the `-command` including the `"& { }"?

Comment: Yes but unfortunately it errorred as mentioned above

Comment: I'm using a workaround by attaching the results.log file to the email instead of it being the body of the email. Not what I was after but it will do for now. No solution has been found yet.